# How to add css to controller view on basis on controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby. I want to add css to controller view on basis of controller names. How can i do so because using all css is making difficult for me to change body color and other attributes using css.

Currently, my application.html.erb has :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

to use all css files. How can i customize it to use particular css with particular controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this in my ApplicationHelper.

```
def controller_stylesheet_link_tag
  return "" if params[:controller].blank?
  begin
    stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller].downcase, :media => "all"
  rescue Exception => e
    e.message
  end
end
```

Then, you just call `<%=controller_stylesheet_link_tag %>` in your layout.